# MySQL Join Multiple Table

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

### News

```
nID  nTitle
-----------
1    test
```

### Keyword

```
kID kWord nID
--------------
 1   abc   1
 2   def   1
 3   ghj   1
```

So i fetch it like

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM news as n, 
                           keyword as k 
                     WHERE n.nID = k.nID");
```

PHP

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo "<div>".$row['nTitle']." - ".$row['kWord']."</div>";
}
```

As you can see, this will output 3 rows of same title with 3 different keyword.
Output :

```
test - abc
test - def
test - ghj
```

What i would like to have it

```
test - abc def ghj
```

Comment: It would help us understand what you want if you provided an example of the expected result.

Comment: edited. sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(kWord) FROM News NATURAL JOIN Keyword GROUP BY News.nID
```

But what's the interest ?